# How to get children and parent book pages

Tags: nodes

I have nid of a book page. I need the nid of the parent and nid of all direct and indirect childs.

How to retrieve the parent and child IDs?

Comment: Please elaborate it
I am not able to understand it properly.
Is book node is some kind of node_reference or what?

Answer (score 3):

This is for Drupal 6 but might also apply to Drupal 7.
The hierarchy of a book is created with a menu. When you have the node object in `$node` you'll get the menu link id of the parent in `$node->book['plid']`. You can then load the corresonding node with `menu_link_load()`.

As for the children you have to get the menu that represents the hierarchy of your book with `menu_tree_all_data($node->book['menu_name'])` and then go through that menu to fetch the links you need.